# How does mocha / babel transpile my test code on the fly?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, transpiler

**My question is not about why something is not working, but rather why it is. Yes.**

I have a small [nodeJS command line tool](https://github.com/nocke/photocmd), which contains features that nodeJS does not yet support out of the box, most notably:

- `import` statements
- `String.includes()`.

Thus for delivery(build) I transpile+bundle my source code (using [parcel](https://parceljs.org), just like webpack).

As a positive wonder, all (but one) of my mocha tests run *directly* against my classes, not the bundle. Still, they work! Including many `import` statements. And including an 'ES6 self-test':

```
it( 'String - include', () => {
    var s = 'Southern Bananas'
    assert( s.includes( 'anana' ) )
    assert( !s.includes( 'kiwi' ) )
} )
```

### Thus:

I have String.include in my **test code**, not just in the source under test. And there is no place where I transpile or bundle my test code… Thus apologies for my dumb question:

### Why is this working? Is there a secret just-in-time compilation somewhere? (and if yes, could I use that for a debug flavour of my deliverable code-under-test as well?)

my `mocha.opts` are rather simple:

```
--require @babel/register
--require ./test/once.js  (nothing special here, either)
--reporter list
--recursive
```

my `.babelrc` has this:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "Electron": "3.0",
                    "Node": "8.0"
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
    ],
    "retainLines": true,
    "comments": false,
    "sourceMaps": true
}
```

`@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` is apparently not to <s>blame</s> praise, as it [explicitly states](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-runtime)

> NOTE: Instance methods such as "foobar".includes("foo") 
>   will not work since that would require modification of 
>   existing built-ins (you can use @babel/polyfill for that).

Is `@babel/polyfill` contained in the *minimalistik-modern* afaik `@babel/preset-env`? What else an I doing right :+)? Is there a way to use this live compilation for my (debug) build as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Long story short

`String.prototype.includes` is supported by Node.js since v6.5. `@babel/register` is causing your code to be compiled on the fly, that's why your `import` statements work. I doubt you need the `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` plugin, unless I'm missing something that you're trying to achieve.

### What can cause this confusion?

I think there are two root causes to this (totally understandable) mystery:

1. The Babel authors have made it *really* easy to use the tool; and sometimes it is hard to know how/when it is being invoked (especially when paired with another tool like Mocha).
2. What is/isn't supported natively by Node.js (in terms of ES2015, ES2016, etc.) has traditionally been hard to keep up with.

So, on to the two mysteries.

### Why does `String.prototype.includes` work?

This one has the easier explanation. `String.prototype.includes` has been supported natively since as early as Node.js v6.5 ([as you can see](https://node.green/#ES2015-built-ins-well-known-symbols-Symbol-match--String-prototype-includes), a vast majority of ES2015 support has been supported since that version).

So, while you're correct that you don't have `@babel/polyfill` configured (as far as I can tell) and that you *would* need it in an environment that doesn't support `String.prototype.includes`, **your environment already supports it**!

From a Node.js v8.x REPL:

```
> 'ES2015'.includes('2015')
true
```

### Why does your `import` statement work?

As you've stated, Node.js v8.x **does not natively support ECMAScript Modules**. However, [there are some good write ups](https://medium.com/@giltayar/native-es-modules-in-nodejs-status-and-future-directions-part-i-ee5ea3001f71) about how it has been enabled as an experimental feature [starting in Node.js v9.x](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v9.x/api/esm.html).

So, you get the following with native Node.js v8.x (via REPL):

```
> import path from 'path';
import path from 'path';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

**The reason your imports are working is because your code is being compiled by Babel using the `@babel/preset-env` preset.** Furthermore, that compilation is being triggered by your `--require @babel/register` Mocha option.

[`@babel/register`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register) works by "bind[ing] itself to node's require and automatically compile files on the fly".

Here is a basic example of `@babel/register` in action:

From the command line:

```
$ node main.js
You will see this, because there is no syntax error!
```

main.js

```
require('@babel/register');
// This next file is compiled on the fly
require('./file1.js');
```

file1.js

```
import path from 'path';
console.log('You will see this, because there is no syntax error!');
```

The good thing is, this is how Mocha recommends you integrate Babel [in their documentation](https://mochajs.org). The `--require` option basically does what the above example does: `require('@babel/register');` is called before Mocha uses `require` to import all of your test files.

Hope this helps! Again, this is a totally understandable mystery in the modern age of rapidly-evolving JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks! Does this on-the-fly-compilation result in temp-files in some ‘hidden’ folder?, or is it all in memory? – And could I subject my [command-line tool itself](https://github.com/nocke/photocmd/blob/master/src/cli/index.js) to be directly run with on-the-fly compilation? (not for “release”, but development naturally...)

Comment: As far as I know, `@babel/register` does compile in memory. But it does maintain a [cache by default](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register#babel-cache-path). That [cache is loaded into memory when it starts up](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-register/src/node.js#L119).

Babel’s for-development-use-only CLI is [`@babel/node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node). It acts the same as the Node CLI, except that it compiles the file before executing. Maybe you could use that? Or integrate `@babel/register` in your CLI's entry point.

Comment: Ha! The “production warning” of [`babel/node`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-node) actually tells me exactly, what I was asking : „You should not be using babel-node in production. It is unnecessarily heavy ... due to the cache being stored in memory. You will also always experience a startup performance penalty as the entire app needs to be compiled on the fly.“ – put to use (/w+w/o npx) [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51530314/444255)

Comment: Since `import` statements are [supported in Node `>= v13.2.0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility), when running Mocha on latest Node versions, does it runs faster because Babel has less/no work to do?