# How to import Javascript from from a Typescript unittest

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mocha.js

How do you run Typescript tests with Mocha for a NPM package that's mostly Javascript?

I have some Javascript/Node.js code that I'm trying to write a unittest for. Since the code does processing on audio samples recorded through the browser, I need to test it by loading wav files from the local dev filesystem.

Since that's a little easier to do in Typescript, I'd like to write my unittests in Typescript and Mocha.

However, Mocha can't seem to find even a basic stub test.

My package structure looks like:

```
src
    index.js
test
    test.ts
    mocha.opts
```

Where test.ts looks like:

```
import MyPackage from '../src';

describe('Simple Math Test', () => {
 it('should return 2', () => {
        assert.equal(1 + 1, 2);
    });
});
```

And my mocha.opts looks like:

```
--require ts-node/register
--recursive
--reporter spec
--ui bdd
--timeout 20000
test/**/*.ts
```

But when I run `mocha` from my project root, it outputs:

```
Error: No test files found
```

If I change my `test.ts` to `test.js`, then it finds it. How do I fix this?

Edit: I found if I run the command `mocha -r ts-node/register test/test.ts`, then it seems to see the Typescript test.

However, it still can't import my Javascript package:

```
Cannot find module '../src' or its corresponding type declarations.

import MyPackage from '../src';
```

Comment: I think `test/**/*.ts` should be `tests/**/*.ts` to match the folder name, though I would expect the mocha.opts to be in the project root in this case

Comment: @apokryfos That's just a typo in my question. My code uses the correct name everywhere and matches the pattern in mocha.opts.

Answer (score 0):

`mocha` by default won't run ts tests, try adding `--extension js,ts`

Comment: Thanks. That partially works. However, now mocha throws the error: `import MyPackage from '../src'; SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Even if I comment that out, it seems to choke on all the other Typescript-specific syntax, as though it's still treating everything as Javascript. I've seen projects that use Mocha to run tests written in Typescript, so Mocha definitely supports Typescript.

Comment: I believe that is a separate issue with transpilation, `mocha` doesn't understand the ES6 `import` syntax, you'll have to use transpiling tool like babel or install the `esm` package. Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60522428/5801142

Comment: Are you sure? [This package](https://github.com/peterkhayes/pitchfinder) has tests using that syntax with mocha and es5.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's going on without looking at your `tsconfig.json` and `package.json`, I've created a minimal ts-js interop boilerplate: https://github.com/steventhan/minimal-ts-js-interop-boilerplate. Can you try matching the setup?